# CSS Stylish popup background

Tags: html, css, stylish

I'm very very bad with CSS (I do not understand syntax at all), I'm just using my knowledge to tinker with code.
I'm using Chrome with Stylish addon, and I want to make dark wikipedia but with my preferences.
I took some code from stylish and just changed colors, but now it's something new where I have
to add stuff so I'm stuck.
It's obviously made in chrome, so it's temporary. This is my problem:

http://imgur.com/a/9IYI3

And my question is how to make that box opaque with like #555 color, without destroying everything else.

Here is code that I'm using: [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/1yt1N86J)

Comment: you might should consider a css tutorial instead of asking this question here because in future you will run into problems and than have to ask again. and its very easy to learn css. can be learned in 1 hour. so give your self a chance to learn something thats good for you :)

Comment: So you want to make just the pop up red, and leave everything else transparent?

Comment: You can't, that's what's the `rgba()` is for - which stands for `red, green, blue, alpha` (with alpha being the opaque factor). If you make it `#f00` you are using hexadecimal colors, which don't support alpha. (Or do I not understand your question? In that case, please rephrase it)

Comment: Using `div, tt, a, span[...]...` you are coloring many elements with the same rule. You're probably want something like `.tooltip{ background-color:rgba(100,100,100,.5) }`

Comment: @agrm Thanks man, that was what I needed, but I can't give you +1 :(.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: note that **opacity** will change the opacity of everything in the element it is applied to. Depending on the situation, **rgba** is the best route.

This can be accomplished a couple of ways:

```
#mybox
{
    background-color:#555;
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

Or

```
#mybox
{
    background-color:rgba(85, 85, 85, 0.5);
}
```

The **opacity** property is to change the transparency of an element (0.0 is 0%, while 1.0 is 100%).

The same can be done with **rgba** (red, green, blue, alpha). Alpha being similar to opacity (same affect really).

As Dwza said in the comments, it would be good for you to take some CSS tutorials. A quick Google search will bring up many. This one looks good: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-best-way-to-learn-css--webdesign-11906

Comment: agrm already gave me answer. I don't want to learn another language that I won't be using, I'm just editing someones code to my own preferences. Anyway thanks for help.